# Error in data-binding-validator by Ilhasoft + Kotlin

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to use the Android library  ["Data Binding Validator by Ilhasoft"](https://github.com/Ilhasoft/data-binding-validator) with Kotlin, but I'm getting this error: Unresolved reference: validate.

That is my root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '3.0.0'
    ext.data_binding_validator_verson = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"  

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

That is my APP build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.main.janderson.meuapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

     dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })  

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
    compile "com.github.Ilhasoft:data-binding-validator:$data_binding_validator_verson"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

That is my fragment_cadastrar_user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.main.janderson.meuapp.model.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/cadastrar_user_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cadastrar_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/first_name_user"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/first_name"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{user.firstName}"
                        app:validateEmpty="@{false}" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/last_name_user"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/last_name"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{user.lastName}"
                        app:validateEmpty="@{false}" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="100"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{user.email}"
                        app:validateType='@{"email"}' />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_phone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/phone"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{user.phone}" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_pass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{user.password}"
                        app:validateMinLength="@{4}" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_confir_pass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_repeat_password"
                        android:imeActionLabel="@string/cadastrar"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:maxLines="1" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/new_user_button"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/cadastrar"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And to finish that is my onCreateView in my Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastrar_user, null)

    //Binding Api
    val binding: FragmentCadastrarUserBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity as Activity, R.layout.fragment_cadastrar_user)
    val  validator =  Validator(binding);

    binding.validate.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (validator.validate()) {
            registerUser()
        }
    })

    binding.setUser(user);

    view.user_phone.addTextChangedListener(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher())

    return view
}
```

[And to complement this is a picture with my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G41Z3.png)

Could someone help me on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate` is the id of the button in the example of the library.

You should use the id of the button, on which you want to validate. I think it is `new_user_button`.

So with binding, it should be like `newUserButton`.

So your full example will be like:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastrar_user, null)

    //Binding Api
    val binding: FragmentCadastrarUserBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity as Activity, R.layout.fragment_cadastrar_user)
    val  validator =  Validator(binding);

    // CHANGE IN BELOW LINE
    binding.newUserButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (validator.validate()) {
            registerUser()
        }
    })

    binding.setUser(user);

    view.user_phone.addTextChangedListener(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher())

    return view
}
```